# How do i use more than 8 colors in ncurses?

Tags: c, linux, ncurses

I just started to use ncurses on Linux. I wanted to use more than 8 colors, but there were only 8 available.

How can I use more colors, or create my own by giving them a names, and set their RGB values?

I tried editing a color with init_color, but that will simply replace one of the current 8 instead of creating new ones.

Note: the value of the global var `COLORS` is 256, so I believe I can use up to 256 different colors.

Comment: init_color(COLOR_RED, 700, 0, 0);   http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/color.html

Comment: I guess you are free to define color 8 to color 255 this way

Comment: Also, the constant `COLOR_PAIRS` defines how many colour pairs a system will allow. See [http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/can_change_color.html](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/can_change_color.html). Presumably you could substitute your own numbers in init_color to define new ones. eg `init_color(9, 800, 700, 600);`

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted.
I didn't know i can set my own numbers.
Thanks guys.

Comment: @mikeyq6 you should post your comment as an answer, it's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If your terminal supports it, you should choose (or customize) a terminal description which has more than 8 colors.  As it is, there are a lot of existing terminal descriptions which could be used: most are customized for particular terminals (or terminal emulators).

If your terminal supports it, the corresponding description would have the capability `initc`.  That is used by the library call `init_color`.  The [`xterm-256color`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm-256color) entry has this for instance:

```
initc=\E]4;%p1%d;rgb\:%p2%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p3%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p4%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X\E\\,
```

which tells the library how to translate the three parameters into an escape sequence.  The terminal entries are built up from reusable parts such as [xterm+256color](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm_256color), because some terminals lack the feature you are interested in.  For those, [xterm+256setaf](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm_256setaf) is appropriate.

For reference,

- [Terminal Database](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html#download_database) Most systems have this as base (small) and extra (large) packages.
- [start_color, init_pair, init_color, has_colors, can_change_color, color_content, pair_content, COLOR_PAIR - curses color manipulation routines](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_color.3x.html)
- [My terminal doesn't recognize color](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#no_color)
- [Why only 16 (or 256) colors?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#xterm_16MegaColors)

Answer (score 1):

The constant `COLOR_PAIRS` defines how many colour pairs a system will allow. See:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/can_change_color.html.

You can substitute your own numbers in `init_color` to define new ones. eg `init_color(9, 800, 700, 600);`