# curses.h functionality - adding new colors?

Tags: c, colors, terminal

Assuming can_change_color() returns true, can init_color() add more colors outside the 8 initialized basic colors? Or only modify their RGB values?

Reading through the manpage I was under the impression it could only modify one of the 8 basic colors. But recently I came across some commented code which implied it could add colors beyond the 8 initial.

I haven't found any definitive documentation on this, does anybody know?

Comment: Most probably you'll need to consult another terminfo (or termcap) variable to ask for the number or range of colors the terminal  allows to change.

Comment: After goin through the library and seeing how it works, i suspect that so long as can_change_color() returns true, at a minimum one can get 16 colors going. 8 colors are defined by default, but that only gives 64 different color combinations. as far as i can tell, the remaining bits until the end of that byte are unused. curses uses bits beyond the initial byte to set flags for text attributes like bold, italicized, flashing etc.

Comment: I think everything depends on the terminal capabilities.... if the terminal only supports 4 modifiable colors, then you won't get 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love That Katie Loves Classi, actually this question was [answered a bit ago on Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945710/how-do-i-use-more-than-8-colors-in-ncurses/).  Feel free to read that and enjoy!

Comment: oof. my bad. must not have searched as well as i thought. thanks

Comment: No problem. Stuff happens! :)