# How do I declare additional colors for ncurses?

Tags: c++, ncurses

I've been trying to write a C++ program using the ncurses library, but I find the 8 colors very limiting. After a bit of research I found out that you can actually use 256 colors with xterm-256color, if my terminal supports it, but I have no idea how I'm supposed to invoke the other 248 colors.

Lets say, for example I can declare a pair with `init_pair(1,COLOR_CYAN,COLOR_BLACK);`. But this only works for the first 8 colors.

EDIT: I've found the answer to my question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945710/how-do-i-use-more-than-8-colors-in-ncurses may help too.

Comment: I did echo $TERM and got st-256color but I still only see 8 COLOR variables in my editor's autocomplete.

Comment: If I run `printw("My terminal supports %d colors.\n", COLORS);` I actually get 256 in my terminal.